# Partition offset

Tags: diskpart, partitionmanager

After cleaning my hard disk, I created some new partitions using DiskPart, but there is a parameter called "Offset". I have read about it on internet , but there is a little information available about it, and I wasn't able to understand what it actually means and what's used for.

I created a 4th partition of size 105 GB, but it is showing an offset of  127 GB, is it okay ?

[I have attached a photo of DiskPart showing offset size](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZUkKYp65y6784ps47)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The offset is where your new partition starts from.

How 127 GB was calculated?

Notice the offset of each partition is the sum of: the size of the precedent partition and the last offset. (The first partition starts at 1024KB = 1MB).

The first offset is 1024KB (1MB).

- The first partition has a size of 100MB. The second partition's offset is 101MB (100MB + 1MB).
- The second partition's size is 29GB. The offset for the 3rd partition is 29GB + 101MB which is still 29GB (29.1 GB actually)
- The 3rd partition's size is 97GB. The next (4th) partition will have an offset of 29.1GB + 97GB = ~127GB
- The next partition, if you decide to create a new one, will start from 127GB + 105GB = 232 GB